# The best way in which to test a function that takes value from HTML input element?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, unit-testing

I am attempting to test my function that takes the value of an input element and assigns it to local variable, however I keep receiving type error:

> Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Please see my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-test-working) for live example

html

```
<input #timeInput type="text" [value]="myData">
<button (click)="doSomething()">Click</button>
```

ts

```
 myData = 'initial text';

  @ViewChild('timeInput') tI: any;

  doSomething() {
    this.myData = this.tI.nativeElement.value;
  }
```

test

```
  it('should', () => {
    component.something.nativeElement.value = 'new data';
    component.myFunc();
    expect(component.myData).toEqual('new data');
  })
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-test-qktnke

Comment: I had done this before, but I was still getting the same issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have come up with a working version by seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063005/angular-unit-test-input-value):

```
describe('component: TestComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [ AppComponent ]
    });
  });

  it('should be ok', () => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    let component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();

    let input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#myInput'));
    let el = input.nativeElement;

    expect(el.value).toBe('initial text');

    el.value = 'new data';

    component.doSomething();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.myData).toBe('new data');

  });
});
```